# one-to-many vs many-to-many association design and benefits

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-structures

I have a pretty basic question that confuses me for some strange reason.

I have two tables, one is the table Pages and the other is the Menus. I am wondering, what is the benefits of using another table for mapping? Below is the two implementations that I am thinking:

[image: Two implementations]

The only difference I see is the way that I search. 
For example in the first implementation:

a) if I want all the pages of a specific menu, I'll query all the page_ids of the specific menu name and I'll join them with the id of the table Pages (which is why I think this implementation is more slow).

b) if I want all the menus of a specific page I will search all the menus that have the page_id of the specific page.

In the second implementation is more typical and straightforward (and with more joins).

I think that the second implementation is the right one because it is faster (I guess, because it queries only between ids which is indexes instead of searching in menus names as I mentioned above in a)).

Or is there any other particular reason? Are these two designs identical in a matter of what they can accomplish or are there any other limitations in the first design and I always should choose the second one?

Comment: In your first implementation one menu can only belong to one page, so it's not many-to-many

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two options are NOT identical; the latter is the correct choice to use in a many-to-many design.  Using a joining table means that you can have many pages  (A, B, C) and many menus (1,2,3) and you can associate a set of menus with a set of pages (yielding A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3).

The first design assumes that any given menu can only have 1 page associated with it.  Menu 1 can only be associated with one page (will it be A, B, or C?).  To associate the same menu with multiple pages, you'll need to have one row in your menu table for each associated page.

Answer (score 1):

Your first implementation is a 1 to many, not a many to many.  Your second implementation is a many to many with payload (note: it doesn't usually need an id).

Many to many means you can nave n items mapped to n other items.  1 to many means you only have one item mapping to n items.

If you need many to many, it can only be done in your second implementation.  If you need 1 to many it is done the first way.

Answer (score 1):

Page and menu have a many-to-many relationship.  The question is, is there any information about that relationship you need to track, other than the simple fact of the relationship?

If you published magazines, for example, you might have a person<-->magazine relationship that was M2M - persons could subscribe to multiple magazines and magazines could have multiple subscribers.  But there's information about the intersection of magazine and person that you would want to track - start date, expiration date, etc.  Using an intersection table gives you a place to put these.

I've been doing this sort of stuff for some time, and I can think of a fair number of instances where I had a M2M where the intersection had nothing to record other than the existence of the intersection, as the system was initially implemented.  In nearly every case, though, the user later asked for an enhancement that would require additional information about the relationship.

So I use intersections, always.